# Why std::execution::par_unseq doesn't work?

Tags: parallel-processing, c++17, g++

What could be a reason the following code doesn't run parallel ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <execution>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> parts(10);
    std::iota(parts.begin(), parts.end(), 0);

    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,
                  parts.begin(), parts.end(), [&](int part) {
        usleep(1'000'000);
        std::cout << part << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

This is **Linux Debian** running on **AMD** and the code is compiled by the following command

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fopenmp -O2 -o test test.cpp
```

The code should output the numbers 0..9 within about 1 second. Now it takes about 10 seconds because the code doesn't run parallel.

Btw. The usleep() function can be replaced by some other calculation heavy function but it doesn't change the situation.

**EDIT:**

I did "sudo apt install libtbb-dev" and then compiled with -ltbb which must be the latest parameter in compilation command or it doesn't work. Problem solved. Thank you @Ted Lyngmo !

Comment: Unsuitable as an answer: Installing Intel oneAPI (Thread Building Blocks - or TBB for short) on your machine could help. Then, `-ltbb` when compiling

Comment: This is AMD cpu or doesn't it matter in this case ?

Comment: Not that I've noticed. I've used TBB on both Intel and AMD's

Comment: Ok. Thx for the idea. I'll try it too.

Comment: You're welcome!  Installing TBB _may_ help if the implementation is capable of using it.  The answer to your question is however in my answer below and your implementation may actually not be able to use TBB or any other backend to actually do what you expected.

Comment: I did "sudo apt install libtbb-dev" and then compiled with -ltbb which *must* be the latest parameter in compilation command or it doesn't work. Problem solved. Thank you @Ted Lyngmo !

Comment: There you go! Glad it helped!

Comment: Add answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I did answer it an hour ago. It's below. Just refresh if you don't see it right now. I did not include recommendations for libraries or such in the answer since that's not on topic for SO, but I did describe the problem and possible remedy for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parallel execution policies describes the kinds of parallelism **allowed**.

The implementation is allowed to fallback on a sequential execution policy if a parallel one is not implemented, which seems to be the case for you. In terms of implementation details, it could look like this in the header file:

```cpp
#ifdef __has_some_parallel_backend
use_parallel_backend(first, last);
#else
use_sequential_fallback(first, last);
#endif
```

Some implementations can *conditionally* use these parallel policies depending on what additional packages you've got installed.

Comment: What do you mean "if parallel one is not implemented" ?

Comment: @R.Post Many implementations rely on other implementations for the parallel execution part. If none is integrated, the implementation will fallback on a sequential policy.